# Как покрасить строку в GridView в Android через одну

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview

[image: в таком порядке]

Мне нужно сделать таблицу с чередующимися цветами строк, я выбрал GridView, чтобы динамически добавлять, но никак не получается сделать цвет на строку

Comment: создайте наследника Custom GridView

Comment: @Style-7 В грид вью создать еще один грид вью?